# Android custom revel animation over image

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I am looking for a reveal animation on top of an image.

[image]

1. User clicks on the thumbnail and opens the image in full-screen which looks like (A). i.e, the image is covered.
2. User clicks the button and the image starts to reveal top to bottom. Going from (A) -> (B) -> (C) in a smooth transition.

The closest I found was this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25ul2xs4u7U

Comment: check this link [reveal-animation-](http://www.edumobile.org/android/reveal-animation-example-introduced-in-android-5-0/) it may help you

Answer (score 1):

for the reveal animation, you can use GitHub library if you're `targetsdkversion` is below 15 else you can use below code.

```
private void show(final View view) {

  int cx = (view.getLeft() + view.getRight()) / 2;
  int cy = (view.getTop() + view.getBottom()) / 2;

  int finalRadius = Math.max(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
  Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, cx, cy,
    0, finalRadius);
  anim.setDuration(1000);

  view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  anim.start();
 }

 private void hide(final View view) {

  int cx = (view.getLeft() + view.getRight()) / 2;
  int cy = (view.getTop() + view.getBottom()) / 2;

  int initialRadius = view.getWidth();

  Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, cx, cy,
    initialRadius, 0);
  anim.setDuration(1000);

  anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
  });

  anim.start();
 }
```

**Link:**
https://github.com/HendraAnggrian/reveallayout
https://github.com/Jaouan/Revealator
http://www.edumobile.org/android/reveal-animation-example-introduced-in-android-5-0/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was actually looking for details about how to implement custom animation (clipping). In this case, the inbuilt circular reveal is used which is different from the reveal mentioned in the question. What I want is more like a rectangular window sliding down.

Comment: Hey @anudeep2011 did you ever get anything for this